# How do I uninstall Miktex on Mac

Tags: installing, mac, macos

I have installed Miktex from the Miktex site due to bad advice from other people, and I realized that Mactex might be better. I want to uninstall Miktex now, but I don't know how to do it. The uninstall button under cleanup will not work and I tried resetting the Tex installation to factory defaults, but still, I could not find a way to uninstall. I don't want to just delete the files for fear that some remanent of Miktex will remain. I have also tried looking online for help but the only thing I found dealt with homebrew, which I am not sure will work.

Comment: depends on how you installed it. usually apps are deleted by dragging them in the bin and clear the bin

Comment: I installed Miktex off of the Mixtex site by going to downloads and installing the Miktex for OS X 10.11 (or later) (64-bit)

Comment: go to `Applications` folder and drag the app to the bin. then clear the bin. this removes the installation, but could leave some remnant files, which are dormant and don't take up much hard disk space.

Comment: I'd prefer to get rid of all of the remnant files though

Comment: @naphaneal I'm afraid MiKTeX installs things in `/usr/local/bin`; even if only symbolic links, they will be bad.

Comment: @egreg either Christian Schenk provides a uninstall guide or someone else does. I couldn't find any solutions and can't draw up one myself as I retired my Mac over 4 years ago and it was not running the latest Mac OS.

Answer (score 2):

I emailed Christian Schenk himself and it turns out that all I really needed to do was drag the Miktex Console icon in Launchpad to the trash. I am assuming that resetting Miktex will get rid of most, if not all of the remnant files.

Comment: You'll probably want to remove `~/bin` as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
miktexsetup cleanup
sudo miktexsetup --shared=yes cleanup
sudo rm -fr /Applications/MiKTeX\ Console.app
```

Reference: https://miktex.org/howto/install-miktex-mac  "Removing MiKTeX" header